# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in MenuComponent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to `React`. I'm building up an app in which `MainComponent` is the container component and `MenuComponent` and `DishDetail` are the presentation components.

When I'm running the code in the browser it is showing cannot read property 'map' for undefined in `MenuComponent` at line 11.

I have checked it and have done it as instructed in my lecture but still facing this problem. I'm attaching all the files here :

MainComponent:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Navbar, NavbarBrand } from 'reactstrap';
import Menu from './MenuComponent';
import DishDetail from './DishdetailComponent';
import  { DISHES } from '../shared/dishes';

class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dishes: DISHES,
      selectedDish : null
    };
  }

  onDishSelect(dishId) {
    this.setState({ selectedDish: dishId});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar dark color="primary">
          <div className="container">
            <NavbarBrand href="/">Ristorante Con Fusion</NavbarBrand>
          </div>
        </Navbar>
        <Menu dishes={this.state.dishes} onClick={(dishId) => this.onDishSelect(dishId)} />
        <DishDetail selectedDish={this.state.dishes.filter((dish) => dish.id === selectedDish(dishId))[0]} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

MenuComponent :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import { Media } from 'reactstrap';
import { Card, CardImg, CardImgOverlay, CardText, CardBody,CardTitle } from 'reactstrap';

class Menu extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
   }

   render() {
      const menu = this.props.dishes.map((dish) => {
         return(
            <div key={dish.id} className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
               {/* <Media tag="li">
                  <Media left middle>
                        <Media object src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                  </Media>
                  <Media body className="ml-5">
                     <Media heading>{dish.name}</Media>
                     <p>{dish.description}</p>
                  </Media>
               </Media>  */}
               <Card key={dish.id} onClick={() => this.props.onDishSelect(dish.id)}>
                  <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                  <CardImgOverlay>
                      <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                  </CardImgOverlay>
                </Card>
            </div>
         );
      });
      

      return(
         <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
               {/* <Media list>
                  {menu}
               </Media> */}
               {menu}
            </div>
         </div>
      );
   }
}

export default Menu;
```

Comment: 1. what is DISHES : import  { DISHES } from '../shared/dishes'; an array or what?  2.if you dont want to change state.dishes so there is no need to put DISHES  in state, you can directly use: does  <Menu dishes={DISHES }

Answer (score 0):

That's basically saying that the value from `this.props.dishes` is undefined.

Make sure that the value that you're importing below is an array (and it's valid).

```js
import { DISHES } from '../shared/dishes';
```

Also, you can use the `DISHES` variable directly instead of storing it into the state, like this:

```js
<Menu dishes={DISHES} onClick={(dishId) => this.onDishSelect(dishId)} />
```